# Dynamically loaded AngularJS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fancybox, angularjs-controller

I'm just looking to try AngularJS as it looks very promising.

I am using fancybox to load my pages in my current application like so:

```
$.fancybox({
    'href' : 'pages/example.php',
    'type' : 'ajax',
    'fitToView' : true
});
```

I am using the exact code from example 4 [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/08/learn-angularjs-5-examples/) for the Instant Search.

I know the controller is not being executed but I am not sure as to the reason.

UPDATE: I now see that if I load the AngularJS script at the end of the body it works. Is there a command to do the same thing i.e. re-init?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(function($){
  $.fancybox({
    'href' : 'pages/example.php',
    'type' : 'ajax',
    'fitToView' : true
  });
});
```

and make sure you have initialized jQuery and fancybox in that specific order. Also check you are not getting any js errors that may void your script

Comment: I can't change the way pages are loaded as that will affect the whole application, I was just wondering is there a command to run that retries the controller so to speak once the page has loaded? I am not familiar with how AngularJS works so I'm not sure why it is failing. How does the controller normally get initialised? Is it just when the browser loads the element with the controller listed or does it happen on document ready?